# R Data Table replace missing values with average from preceding and next value

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table with missing values (`NAs`) in each column:

`DT = data.table(a = c(1,2,3,4,5,NA,6,7,8,NA), b = c(NA,4,NA,8,10,1,2,3,4,5))`

I would now like to replace each NA with an average value based on the previous and the next value. If the first entry per column contains NA, then replace it by the next value. If the last value contains NA, then replace it by the previous value. I'd like to receive a result like this:

```
     a  b
 1:  1  4
 2:  2  4
 3:  3  6
 4:  4  8
 5:  5 10
 6: 5.5  1
 7:  6  2
 8:  7  3
 9:  8  4
10:  8  5
```

I thought about using `frollmean()`. For example:

```
DT[, frollmean(a, n = 3, align = "center", na.rm = TRUE)]
> NA 2.0 3.0 4.0 4.5 5.5 6.5 7.0 7.5  NA
```

I could then repeat `frollmean()` with `align = "right"` and `align = "left"`. In the end I would have three new columns for each column from my original data table. Then I could iterate through every `NA` in the original data table and replace it with the value that is generated in one of the three new columns. This sounds pretty tedious and unnecessary. Therefore I'd like to know the following:

1. Is there a simpler way to replace the `NAs` from each column?
2. Is there a way to compute values only for rows that contain `NAs` to save computational time?

Comment: You may use e.g. `zoo::na.approx`; `DT[ , lapply(.SD, na.approx, rule = 2)]`. [Several similar posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bdata.table%5d%20na.approx).

Comment: @Henrik thanks for this comment! I have problems finding a decent documentation explaining what exactly the argument 'rule' does. stats::approx defines rule 2 as `if it is 2, the value at the closest data extreme is used.` How does that lead to the `NA` in the middle to be averaged by the previous and next record? I get the results I want but I want to make sure that I understand the method correctly.

Comment: I think it is easiest to think about `rule` in terms of _extrapolation_ - should _constant_ extrapolation be performed or not? See e.g. the examples in `?approx`: "### Treatment of 'NA's". An even simpler example: `x = c(NA, 1, NA, 4, NA)`; `na.approx(x)`, defaults explicit: `na.approx(x, na.rm = TRUE, rule = c(1, 1))`, i.e. linear interpolation at one point between 1 and 4 (in this case with only one `NA`, the same as the mean of 1 and 4).; `na.approx(x, na.rm = FALSE, rule = 1)`, keep leading/trailing `NA`;

Comment: `na.approx(x, na.rm = FALSE, rule = 2:1)`, constant extrapolation of leading `NA`; `na.approx(x, na.rm = FALSE, rule = 1:2)`, constant extrapolation of trailing `NA`; `na.approx(x, na.rm = FALSE, rule = c(2, 2))`, or with recycling of `rule`:  `na.approx(x, na.rm = FALSE, rule = 2)`, extrapolation of both leading and trailing `NA`.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the below code

### code

```r
  data.table(a = c(1,2,3,4,5,NA,6,7,8,NA), b = c(NA,4,NA,8,10,1,2,3,4,5)) %>% 
    mutate(across(c(a,b), ~lag(.x), .names = 'lag{col}'), across(c(a,b), ~lead(.x), .names = 'lead{col}'), 
           mean_a=ifelse(is.na(a),rowMeans(across(c(laga,leada)),na.rm=T),NA),
           mean_b=ifelse(is.na(b),rowMeans(across(c(lagb,leadb)),na.rm=T),NA)
           )
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

### output

```r
     a  b laga lagb leada leadb mean_a mean_b
 1:  1 NA   NA   NA     2     4     NA      4
 2:  2  4    1   NA     3    NA     NA     NA
 3:  3 NA    2    4     4     8     NA      6
 4:  4  8    3   NA     5    10     NA     NA
 5:  5 10    4    8    NA     1     NA     NA
 6: NA  1    5   10     6     2    5.5     NA
 7:  6  2   NA    1     7     3     NA     NA
 8:  7  3    6    2     8     4     NA     NA
 9:  8  4    7    3    NA     5     NA     NA
10: NA  5    8    4    NA    NA    8.0     NA
```